# How to merge arrays in PHP without key preservation?

Tags: php, arrays

Am I overlooking a function in PHP that will merge arrays without preserving keys? I've tried both ways of these ways: `$arrayA + $arrayB` and `array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB)` but neither are working as I expected.

What I expect is that when I add `array(11, 12, 13)` and `array(1, 2, 3)` together that I would end up with `array(11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3)`.

I created a function of my own which handles it properly, though I was trying to figure out if it was the best way of doing things or if there's an easier or even a build in way that I'm just not seeing:

```
function array_join($arrayA, $arrayB) {
  foreach($arrayB as $B) $arrayA[] = $B;
  return $arrayA;
}
```

**Edit:**
`array_merge()` was working as intended, however I had the function running in a loop and I was using the incorrect variable name inside the function, so it was only returning a partial list as is what I was experiencing. For example the loop I was using ended on `array(13, 1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually tested your code? because array_merge should be enough:

From the documentation of [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge):

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the **values of one are appended to the end of the previous one**. (*emphasis are mine*)

```
<?php

$a1 = array(11, 12, 13);
$a2 = array(1, 2, 3);

$x = array_merge($a1, $a2);
print_r($x);
```

It print this on my console:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had a function running in a loop and I was using the wrong variable inside the `array_merge` function so I was only getting a partial list. I will mark your answer as accepted due to its robust explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array(11, 12, 13);
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3);
print_r(array_merge($arr1,$arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
function array_join($arrayA, $arrayB) {
  foreach($arrayB as $B) $arrayA[count($arrayA)] = $B;
  return $arrayA;
}
```